# Creating a global map variable in xquery library module in Marklogic

Tags: dictionary, xquery, marklogic

I need to add a map to a library module. The map's used by most of its functions. I have a function that populates the map.

```
declare variable $map as map:map :=local:populateMap();

declare function local:populateMap() {
  let $map:=map:map()
   let $dummy1:=for $id in cts:search(/document/id,cts:element-query(xs:QName("document"),cts:and-query(())),"unfiltered" )
      let $dummy2:=map:put($map,$id/fn:string(),someValueCorrespondingToCurrentId)
       return ()
   return $map     

};

other functions that use the map
```

My documents look like this:

```
<document>
 <id>id</id>
<otherElements>
 ...........
</otherElements> 
</document>
```

The code inside `local:populateMap()` looks a bit awkward to me especially for the use of those dummy variables. What would be a better approach to do this?

Comment: I would consider if you are really implementing this in the best possible way? It seems to me that there may be a code smell here to a have a module global variable initialised by a function, so that it can be used in the other functions.

I would tend to avoid global variables in place of passing the variable explicitly to the function, in this way each function is self-contained in its external data dependencies and you can reason about the function from its signature.

Comment: Thanks for raising this. If you mean passing the map as an argument  to the functions that use it, the problem with this is that this module is a library one. The functions are called from other main modules. Would it ideal to create the map in those caller modules?

Comment: I would suggest so yes. My passing arguments explicitly it also makes testing easier as you can really test a function without dependencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a path range index on /document/id:

```
declare function local:populateMap() {
  map:new((
    cts:values(
      cts:path-reference("/document/id"))
    ) ! map:entry(., someValueCorrespondingToCurrentId)
  ))
};
```

Suppose `someValueCorrespondingToCurrentId` is something that comes from the same document as the id and also has a range index on it.

```
declare function local:populateMap() {
  map:new((
    cts:values(cts:path-reference("/document/id"))) ! 
      map:entry(., 
        cts:values(
          cts:SOMETHING-reference(
            reference-spec, 
            (), 
            "limit=1", 
            cts:path-range-query("/document/id", "=", .)
          )
        )
      )
  ))
};
```

[The "!" operator](http://developer.marklogic.com/blog/simple-mapping-operator) concisely replaces your inner FLWOR, while map:new and map:entry replace the outer one. In the second code block above, I'm looking up the cts:*-reference that occurs in the same document as the current id. In both cases, all values are retrieved from indexes, so documents don't need to be loaded from disk.

Comment: When using indexes you might not even need to cache results in a map:map, particularly if you are going to need just a limited number of values from the total set..

Answer (score 1):

If find the following syntax much more readable and more in style with a functional programming language:

```
declare function local:populateMap() {
  map:new((
    for $id in cts:search(/document/id,cts:element-query(xs:QName("document"),cts:and-query(())),"unfiltered" )
    return map:entry($id/string(), someValueCorrespondingToCurrentId)
  ))
};
```

This code creates a new map with the given map entries. In the code sample you provided for each iteration a new map should be created.

Comment: `map:put` doesn't create a new map:map, but has a side-effect. That is also necessary for the original code to work, otherwise $map would not have returned the full map:map, just an empty one. I guess both code will be roughly equally fast. But I do agree, I also like `map:new` and `map:entry` better..

Comment: Thanks. That should be it.

Comment: @grtjn well, I didn't test it in ML, but in fact I think the code sample provided _should_ return an empty map (it does in BaseX). XQuery is side-effect free and if the `$map` is manipulated I would say ML is not behaving according to the spec. But I agree with the performance aspect, as normally an implementation should be clever enough to not create a completely new object.

Comment: That is the reason why map:new and map:entry were added as an alternative to map:map and map:put..

Comment: Maps have been around in MarkLogic for very long, and can be very convenient. You can read all about them here: http://developer.marklogic.com/blog/im-a-map

Comment: @grtjn Thanks for the pointers, I wasn't aware that maps have been introduced in ML 5, so `map:put` was probably there long before the XQuery 3.1 spec. Still, I think when 3.1. is introduced in ML this behavior has to be changed accordingly. It was just confusing to me that in ML `map:put` isn't the actual `map:put` function from the 3.1 spec.

Comment: MarkLogic doesn't officially support XQuery 3 yet, though it is partially available. Hence the usual first line being `query version "1.0-ml"`, which gives you all the things like try catch, and parts from XQuery 3 as well..